# ETL Programming Methodology

Tags: ssis, etl, methodology, datastage

Data Stage Methodological development at all projects that i took place was by a principle of Keep It Simple. That meens that every job contain as less sources/targets for a maintenance in the future will be very easy and simple. 
I noticed that in the Microsoft projects, it's not like that at all. Every SSIS Pkg is very loaded and complicated. So the maintenance become very complicated.
I wonder why.
Is there a technical reason for that? Is there some limit of Pkg-s number that a Job can contain?

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

The more complex the job the more file descriptors it has open.

We had a really complex job and hit the limit, see link for details;

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21404155

Which basically meant we had to rewrite the job and make it less complex.

Hope this helps with your question